# How to make Eclipse's content assist behavior similar to Visual Studio's IntelliSence

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, intellisense, content-assist

I'm a C# developer and recently started to use Eclipse IDE to write Android apps. The most noticeable change for me is that content assist doesn't popup automatically. Is there a way to do so? In VS it pops up almost always.

P.S. And a more general question: how to make eclipse to look more like VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey the best solution I've found, in terms of getting eclipse to pop up for everything I type, is going into windows > preferences > java > editor > content assist and adjusting the trigger characters. It's normally only set to ".". I changed mine to ".(abcdefgh..." etc. It's not quite as beautiful a solution as I'm sure you'd like, but it does an acceptable job making sure I don't have to remember what I've named things.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist and check "Enable auto activation".

And what do you mean by "look like VS"? Fonts, colors, ...?

Comment: Yep. GUI, Fonts, Colors, Menus, Key bindings. The most annoying is GUI. It looks so like 2000's

Comment: auto activation is already enabled and it works only after I type dot. I want it to also complete words like 'public', new variables type etc.